# How do I change teams in Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode4.4

In 4.3 and under the first time you tried to do a team based action, such as refresh provisioning profiles, it would ask you to log in. It no longer does this in 4.4, it just assumes a team and refreshes... how do I teach Xcode there are multiple teams? It lists them under the teams in side bar of the organizer, but won't let me refresh their profiles, or select them when creating new profiles.

To clarify, each team is under a different developer ID, and I can't find any way to log in to different developer IDs to refresh the provisioning profiles. I *can* still log in to different ID's when submitting apps to the app store, however this doesn't seem to affect the provisioning profile refresh login ID.

Comment: The solution thanks to ezod is to delete the daw2.apple.com keychain entries, forcing it to re-log in. It's important to note that you have to quit XCode completely between logins or it may get confused and remove your profiles due to the 2 stage login.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in Xcode 4.4.1 (released yesterday, 7th August 2012).
And as Ivan stated correctly: It seems that all profiles from all teams are synced as long as you have the **same apple id** across all teams.
(Tested this by removing all profiles from Xcode in the Organizer and hit "Refresh")

**Update:**

If you have different apple ids across multiple teams and the login dialog is still missing, you might have saved your credentials in your keychain. See comments #2 and #3 of this answer for a workaround.

Comment: I don't have the same apple ID across all teams, I have a unique one for each team. It still doesn't prompt me which one to log in to. Maybe I can merge my main ID into each team, but then each of my computers is currently syncing under a different ID and since there's no way to change it I would have to merge all IDs into all teams...

Comment: Ok - maybe as a workaround delete the corresponding entry in your OS X keychain. So Xcode will not be able to connect with the saved account and will ask for your credentials. Then simply don't tick the checkbox to "Remember password in Keychain"

Comment: Thanks, that worked. You have to delete the daw2.apple.com entries in the keychain. Important note: you have to quit XCode before refreshing a new account. The first time you refresh it logs you in twice, if you refresh again it logs you in again but only the second login. The first login apparently gets your teams, the second actually gets the profiles etc. So if you're logged in to the wrong team from the first time it can't see the teams under the new login and deletes any profiles under that account instead...

Answer (score 3):

There is a strange way to add a new identity (user/pass). If you build and archive and then go to Distribute -> Save for Enterprise, then open the Code Signing Identity list there will be an item marked "Refresh code signing identity" at the end. If you select it you'll be prompted to enter username and password. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, since I found this page searching for XCode 5.1 - getting XCode to sync new teams on the same Apple ID, click '`View Details`' on any teams that are there to see the provisioning profiles for that specific team, then hit the `refresh` icon.  It will also download any new teams added to the ID.